# Smart Design for Blog + Woocommerce + LearnDash + Forum/Bodyboss

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, blog, domain

I am migrating a page plus new to Wordpress and picked a nice project for a steep learning curve :). I am looking for input, on how to best design this (1 domain, subdomains, or any other structure) for a good performance:

```
- static page (20 pages)
- blog (100 posts and growing) - currently about 1k-2k hits a month
- LearnDash integration
- Woocommerce shop (for courses and physical products)
- Future: Forum or some kind of a social platform
```

I read in multiple places that it is not recommended to use more than **20 plugins**, otherwise the whole page will be slow.

If I count the needed plugins I surpass them significantly:

**Page + Blog + Shop (16 Plugins)**

```
- Astra Pro
- Elementor
- Elementor Pro
- Folders (for the management of media/sites/posts)
- Preso Player
- Rank Math SEO 
- Starter Templates 
- Ultimate Addons for Gutenberg (for posts, as we want to keep them simple)
- Woocommerce 3x
- WPForms Lite  
- Firewall (some kind)
- Mail system integration (with woocommerce)
- Cookies plugin
- WP Statistics
```

**LearnDash absolute minimum (11 Plugins)**

```
- the various plugins to make a great course; I talked to LearnDash and all their Add-ons are plugins and behave as such
```

**Social 2+?**

```
- Buddyboss / Forum
- Spam plugin
```

I might realize I actually need 1 or two more (security?) as I develop everything. So right now I am easily at **30 plugins**.

My initial though was to have 1 WP for the site/blog/woocommerce and 1 subdomain for LearnDash (little though went into the forum, as that I am still in the process of learning all the other things and trying to get those running) and somehow connect them.

Of course I want on my static page / blog to show the products and courses overview (LD course grid plugin). So I wrote to LearnDash and they said that LearnDash and Woocommerce need to be on the same domain, otherwise I would need some Zapier intergartion and that would be quite complex.
Plus if I integrated it on a separate domain, I would not be able to show the courses on the other domain, because the grid plugin is only available on the one where you have LD installed.

I found an article stating that I could also work with webhooks for woocommerce being on the blog site (and LD by itself) or with Uncanny Automator Pro, but there is very little details available, plus also found a page mentionen that that does not work reliably....

Our Wordpress is hosted at SiteGround with

```
- nginx direct delivery on
- nginx dynamic cache on
- and memcached can be turned on
- PHP memory_limit 768M
- DB MySQL connections 500
```

My questions are:

Is it likely (there is no sure thing I know) that I can run this from one site (any guesses of up to how many congruent users) at a reasonable loading speed?

How would you structure such a site?

Thank you very much for sharing your knowledge and experience!

Comment: There is no limit on how many plugins you can use.  The more you use, the more code the server runs.  But more importantly, it's how ambitious the plugins are in what they provide and how efficiently they're written.  A lot of plugins are written to appeal to as large a user base as possible, which means they come with a lot of stuff that you yourself may not need.  Honestly, going through your list of 'necessary' plugins, I'd argue with an ambitious project, they're actually the opposite and NOT necessary....

Comment: ...a lot of the plugins you list are specifically designed for the 'low barrier to entry, anyone can do this' side of Wordpress.  They are point and click plugins which remove the need for custom coding.  They work perfectly fine for what they are.  But for a complex, ambitious project like the one you're attempting, I would strongly advise you take a different approach and look to build out exactly what you need and only that.  As for LD's add-ons all being plugins, one would hope they are written efficiently and wouldn't impact the server.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.